# How can I determine if I have a unique Arc when it's dropped?

Tags: rust

I've an `Arc<Mutex<Thing>>` field in a struct which is cloned many times. It is shared between concurrent threads. `Drop::drop` is called for each clone as it goes out of scope. Is there any way to determine when `Drop::drop` is called for the last (unique) `Arc<Mutex<Thing>>`?

- It's clear that strong_count is subject to data races (I've seen them). So, you can't count on `Arc::strong_count() == 1` (no pun intended).
- I found that I couldn't use `Arc::try_unwrap()` due to a move issue.
- `Arc::is_unique()` is private.

Other than keeping a `Arc<AtomicUsize>` field, which is incremented on clone and decremented on drop, is there any way to determine if a `drop` is for a unique `Arc<Mutex<Thing>>`?

Here's an MRE:

```
use std::sync::{Arc};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Action {
    One, Two, Three
}

// Thing trait which operates on an Action, which should be a enum, allowing for
// different action sets.
trait Thing<T> {
    fn disconnected(&self);
    fn action(&self, action: T);
}

// There are many instances of an ActionController.
// There may be zero or more clones of an instance.
// The final drop of the instances should call thing.disconnected()
// In a multi-core environment, the same instance may be running on multiple cores
// ActionController should not be generic.
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ActionController {
    id: usize,
    thing: Arc<dyn Thing<Action>>,
}
impl ActionController {
    fn new(id: usize, thing: Box<dyn Thing<Action>>) -> Self {
        Self { id, thing: Arc::from(thing) }
    }
    fn invoke(&self, action: Action) {
        self.thing.action(action);
    }
}

//
// To work around the drop issue, I've implemented Clone for ActionController which
// performs a fetch_add(1) on clone and a fetch_sub(1) on drop. This provides
// suficient information to call disconnected() -- but it just seems like there's
// got to be a better way.
impl Drop for ActionController {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // drop will be called for each clone of an Controller instance. When
        // the unique instance is dropped, disconnected() must be called
        self.thing.disconnected();
    }
}

struct Controlled {}
impl Thing<Action> for Controlled {
    fn disconnected(&self) { println!("disconnected")}
    fn action(&self, action: Action) {println!("action: {:#?}", action)}
}

fn bad() {
    let controlled = Controlled{};
    let controlled = Box::new(controlled) as Box<dyn Thing<Action>>;
    let controller = ActionController::new(1, controlled);
    let clone = controller.clone();
    controller.invoke(Action::One);
    clone.invoke(Action::Two);
    drop (controller);
    clone.invoke(Action::Three);
}

fn main() {
    bad();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn incorrect() {
        bad();
    }
}
```

Comment: `strong_count` is subject to *races* if you use it inappropriately, but not *data races* as the term is normally used. Safe Rust is data-race- free.

Comment: What can you do with this information that you couldn't do in an implementation of `Drop` for `Thing`? If the drop behavior of `Thing` depends on the `Arc` it's stored in, you might be doing something pretty unusual.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would help to clarify what you want. What code needs to know when `drop` is called? Does it need to know _before_ or _after_ it has been called? Example code would be very helpful.

Comment: A MRE is a bit of a challenge, as it’s somewhat complex, involving associates. Let me work on it as it may yield some interesting patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arc::try_unwrap` is probably the intended way to do this - is it possible to restructure your code to avoid the move issues you were running into?

Comment: Maybe storing an `thing: Option<Arc<Mutex<Thing>>>`, and in the drop doing `Arc::try_unwrap(thing.take())`?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to know?  If you have some extra cleanup code that needs to be executed before the `Mutex<Thing>` is dropped, maybe you could use an `Arc<MyLockedThing>` instead, where `MyLockedThing` is a struct containing a `Mutex<Thing>` that impls `Drop` to do the cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to be notified when the data inside the `Arc` is to be dropped. If so, this can be done by implementing `Drop` on the type "inside" the `Arc`.

Define a newtype:

```
struct ThingAction(Box<dyn Thing<Action>>);

impl Thing<Action> for ThingAction {
    fn disconnected(&self) {
        self.0.disconnected()
    }
    
    fn action(&self, action: Action) {
        self.0.action(action)
    }
}
```

And implement `Drop`:

```
impl Drop for ThingAction {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.disconnected()
    }
}
```

Then use the newtype:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct ActionController {
    id: usize,
    thing: Arc<ThingAction>,
}
impl ActionController {
    fn new(id: usize, thing: Box<dyn Thing<Action>>) -> Self {
        Self { id, thing: Arc::new(ThingAction(thing)) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any perfect way to do this without stdlib support (go checkout out `Arc::drop`).

`Weak::strong_count` or `Weak::upgrade` is less subject to races so if you `downgrade` your Arc then drop it, if the weakref's strong count is 0 or trying to `upgrade` it fails you know the `Arc` is dead, but there is no guarantee the current thread killed it, two might have concurrently dropped the `Arc` at the same time before either had the time to check for the weakref's strong count.

I think the only bulletproof way would be to get notified by a `Drop` stored inside the `Arc`, that you're guaranteed is only called once.

Comment: If I downgrade a unique it will go away, never to be heard from again, won’t it?

Comment: Yes. But it should work fine if you just want to know whether the Arc died.

Comment: yes, but it could be in multiple threads which hall determine this concurrently. I need to think about it a bit more. Maybe it is safe.

Comment: That's what I noted in my comment: " there is no guarantee the current thread killed it, two might have concurrently dropped the Arc at the same time before either had the time to check for the weakref's strong count."

Comment: TBF Daniel's answer is probably your best bet, if you can fix the issues around your move.

Comment: It is a bit ugly, but its possible to use another Arc. Performance-wise, the counter is likely a better alternative.